# CSS - Selecting elements based on font-size and dynamically applying styles to that text

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

Is there a way to **select elements** in JavaScript **based on the font-size**?

I want to apply different styles (like font-weight and letter-spacing) dynamically in JavaScript depending on each element's font-size.

We can select all p tags and apply style to them.

```
p {
  color: green;
}
```

I am wondering if I can do something like this (or to that effect; i know the color below won't work) :

```
font-size:14px {
  /* All font that is size 14px is now red*/
  color: red;
}

font-size:16px {
  /* All font that is size 16px is now blue*/
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: yes you can apply style in javascript.

Comment: ??? Describe your use case, share code from your page so we can see what we working with, and phrase a clear concise question - not clear at all what your first sentence means, and without more context cant really help with the second sentence. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a very vague question. Can you please ellaborate what you want to achive?

Comment: Hey I just put a hypothetical example as to what I want. Let me know if the question is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style can be applied from javascript:

```
document.getElementById("[id]").style.[css rule] = [value];
```

and you get style property of element by:

```
window.getComputedStyle([element], null).getPropertyValue('[css rule]')
```

example:

```js
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(all[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size') > "15px") {
    all[i].style.fontWeight = "900";
  } else {
    all[i].style.fontWeight = "100";
  }
}
```

```css
#myPara {
  font-size: 14px;
}
p+p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<p id="myPara">This is some text.</p>
<p>This is some text.</p>
<p>This is some text.</p>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to select elements based on font-size, not ID.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
$( "p" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).css('font-size')=='12px'){
        //Apply Styles
        $(this).css('color','red')
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heinlinaung/tpu5220k/)